# Capture Alert Dialog Button Event

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have added **Acr.UserDialogs** plugin and called as follows, I could able to see a simple alert with a `OK` button. So far so good, but I wonder how to capture `OK` button click event?

```
public void Save()
{
  if (!isExit)
  {
     OnExit(this, null);
  }
  else
  {
     IsValid = false;
     Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Alert("it is not valid");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass a `AlertConfig` and set the `OnOk` action.

```
var alertConfig = new AlertConfig {
    Message = "it is not valid",
    OkText = "Okely",
    OnOk = () => { Debug.WriteLine("ok pressed"); }
};

Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Alert(alertConfig);
```

**UPDATE for Version 7.0+:**

`OnOk` was renamed to `OnAction` see: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/master/src/Acr.UserDialogs/AlertConfig.cs#L16

```
var alertConfig = new AlertConfig {
    Message = "it is not valid",
    OkText = "Okely",
    OnAction = () => { Debug.WriteLine("ok pressed"); }
};

Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Alert(alertConfig);
```

Comment: I tried to use OnOk but it is giving me an error. Can you help?

Comment: I'm using Acr.UserDialogs v7.0.1 and I have the same problem as @NickKing. Did anybody find the correct answer for the newer versions? Currently I'm using a ConfirmDialog without cancel button text, but that's ugly

Answer (score 0):

In Arc.UserDialogs 7.0.1 you need to do it the following way:

```
var alertConfig = new AlertConfig
{
    Message = message,
    OkText = "AppSyncViewModel_Alert_Retry".Translate(),
    OnAction = YourAction
};
Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IUserDialogs>().Alert(alertConfig);
```